# Parse non-UTC date string as UTC Instant, and print it out in another TimeZone

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, datetime-parsing, datetime-conversion

I am using Java 11.

I have a datetime string which looks like this

**"2023-02-17T03:56:50.254"**

But I know it represents a point in time in UTC time zone.

How do I parse this string taking into account it's actually in UTC (the parsing has to be independent of my default JVM time-zone)?

And then how do I convert it to another string which represents the same date/time in e.g. America/NewYork time zone?

There are many parsing examples here but none of them seems to represent exactly my case.

Comment: "And then how do I" - please restrict yourself to one question per post. I suspect there are *lots* of posts about how to convert an Instant to a specific time zone.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes but this string does not contain the Z suffix while it's actually UTC. I explained that I looked around but didn't find anything quite the same. Most examples assume the input string has the appropriate time zone info, mine doesn't.

Comment: " Yes but this instant does not contain the Z suffix" - an *Instant* doesn't have a Z or not have a Z. By the time you've converted the original string to an Instant, the format of that original string is completely irrelevant... so it really is a separate question, which shouldn't be asked in the same post.

Comment: @JonSkeet I meant of course that the input string doesn't contain Z suffix... come on...

Comment: Either you understand that the resulting Instant is completely independent of the original text - in which case you shouldn't be asking the second question, as it's independent of the first, and a post should ask only one question... or you *don't* understand that, in which case I'm correcting your expectations. Fundamentally I think you should remove the "and then how do I" paragraph.

Comment: `ZonedDateTime ldtZoned = LocalDateTime.parse("2023-04-17T03:56:59.257").atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());ZonedDateTime utcZoned = ldtZoned.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC"));System.out.println(utcZoned.toLocalDateTime());
` is one way

Comment: @g00se: That would be a *bad* way to go, because `atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())` would be interpreting it incorrectly. Sweeper's answer is the right way to go.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm not over-happy with it - but not for that reason ;) It works, correctly adjusting the offset-less datetime string to be the correct time. So, if like me, you're not in UTC, it will adjust that time accordingly. That doesn't happen with Sweeper's afaics

Comment: @g00se: I think you've misinterpreted the question. The string *must not* be adjusted, because it already represents a UTC value. Sweeper's answer doesn't do that *because it shouldn't*.

Comment: @g00se You are making the opposite conversion of the one that I think was asked for (and in any case you are correct, if the default time zone is already in UTC on the date in question, effectively no conversion happens).

Comment: @peter.petrov The down-vote may have been because we have covered all the issues in your Question many many times before in existing Questions & Answers. However, you also got some up-votes, so I took the time to post a complete Answer here.

Answer (score 4):

First, parse the string into a `LocalDateTime`, because that's all there is in the string - a date and a time.

Then, you can convert it to a `ZonedDateTime` or an `Instant`, depending on your interpretation - whether this is a date and time in the `UTC` zone, or a point in time.

```
var parsedResult =
    LocalDateTime.parse(string/*, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME*/)
        .toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC); // for an Instant
//      .atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC); // for a ZonedDateTime
```

After you have either of those, you can use `withZoneSameInstant`/`atZone` respectively to put it into another zone.

```
// if parsedResult is Instant
var atAnotherZone = parsedResult.atZone(anotherZone);
// if parsedResult is ZonedDateTime
var atAnotherZone = parsedResult.withZoneSameInstant(anotherZone);
```

Comment: Ooh, I'd missed the `toInstant` inherited method on LocalDateTime. That's better than going via ZonedDateTime.

Comment: There’s no use for a `ZonedDateTime` here, but depending on further requirements one may consider `.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)` to obtain an `OffsetDateTime`. But only if an `Instant` does not suffice for the situation.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```java
LocalDateTime                           // Represent a date with time-of-day, but lacking the context of a time zone or offset from UTC.
.parse( "2023-02-17T03:56:50.254" )     // Parse text in standard ISO 8601 format.
.atOffset(                              // Assign an offset to this date-with-time.
    ZoneOffset.UTC                      // Constant for an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds.
)                                       // Returns an `OffsetDateTime` object.
.atZoneSameInstant(                     // Adjust from a moment as seen with an offset of zero to being seen with a time zone some number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead/behind UTC.
    ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" )     // Represent a time zone. Name is in format of Continent/Region. 
)                                       // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
.toString()                             // Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format extended wisely to append the name of the zone in square brackets.
```

See this code [run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/AvE9ZA). Notice how the date as well as the time-of-day differ from that of the input.

```
2023-02-16T22:56:50.254-05:00[America/New_York]
```

## Offset versus zone

Per the [Comment by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76072437/parse-non-utc-date-string-as-utc-instant-and-print-it-out-in-another-timezone#comment134162675_76072732), the appropriate class here is `OffsetDateTime` rather than `ZonedDateTime`.

- An ***offset* is merely a number** hours, minutes, and second ahead of or behind the temporal meridian of [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).
- A ***time zone* is a named history** of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region as decided by their politicians. Named in format of `Continent/Region`.

The *java.time* classes offer two classes to represent each concept:

- `ZoneOffset`
- `ZoneId`

And the *java.time* classes offer two classes to represent a moment as seen in each way.

- `OffsetDateTime`
- `ZonedDateTime`

By the way, the [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) class is a more basic building-block class in *java.time*, representing a moment as seen in UTC, always in UTC (an offset of zero).

## `LocalDateTime`

So, yes parse your input as date with time-of-day, a `LocalDateTime`.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2023-02-17T03:56:50.254" ) ;
```

The `LocalDateTime` does *not* represent a moment, as it lacks the context of an offset or zone.

## `ZoneOffet` & `OffsetDateTime`

You said:

> How do I parse this string taking into account it's actually in UTC

If you are certain that date and time was intended to represent a moment "in UTC", that is with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds, then apply a [`ZoneOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneOffset.html) rather than a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) to produce an [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) rather than a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

Java comes with a constant defined for an offset of zero, [`ZoneOffset.UTC`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

## `ZoneId` & `ZonedDateTime`

You asked:

> And then how do I convert it to another string which represents the same date/time in e.g. America/NewYork time zone?

Define your desired time zone. Use `ZoneId` for a zone (`ZoneOffset` for a mere offset).

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ;
```

[Apply that time zone](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#atZoneSameInstant(java.time.ZoneId)) to produce a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( zoneId ) ;
```

In this example, **both `odt` and `zdt` represent the same simultaneous  moment**, the same point on the timeline. That moment is what is meant by “Instant” in the method name `atZoneSameInstant` and in the class `Instant`. The `odt` and `zdt` variables differ in their wall-clock time & calendar. Like someone in Reykjavík Iceland calling someone in Los Angeles California — when each party simultaneously glances at the clock and calendar hanging on their respective wall, they see a different time and date.

In contrast, the `LocalDateTime` variable named `ldt` does *not* represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline. That class purposely lacks the context of a time zone or offset. So the `LocalDateTime` class cannot represent a moment.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the comments and answers. Putting them all together, I think this is what I needed.

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main001 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        // Do first test with a winter date
        String text = "2023-02-17T03:56:50.254";
                
        LocalDateTime local = LocalDateTime.parse(text);
        ZonedDateTime zdt = local.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
        Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();
        
        System.out.println(instant);
        
        DateTimeFormatter formatter =
                DateTimeFormatter
                .ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")
                .withZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
        
        System.out.println(formatter.format(instant));
        
        // Do second test with a summer date
        text = "2023-07-17T03:56:59.257";
        
        local = LocalDateTime.parse(text);
        zdt = local.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
        instant = zdt.toInstant();
        
        System.out.println(instant);
        
        formatter =
                DateTimeFormatter
                .ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")
                .withZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
        System.out.println(formatter.format(instant));

    }

}
```

Output:

```
2023-02-17T03:56:50.254Z
2023-02-16T22:56:50.254
2023-07-17T03:56:59.257Z
2023-07-16T23:56:59.257
```

Comment: I recommend `OffsetDateTime odt = local.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);` (and then of course `Instant instant = odt.toInstant();`).Using `ZonedDateTime` for a date and time in UTC is overkill.